# How to replace bash variable with command line arguments

Tags: bash

My bash script bash.sh only contains one line

```
echo "${abc:=123}"
```

I learned that `:=` is used to assign default values. So when I run `bash.sh abc=abc`, I expect the output to be `abc`.

However, the output is still `123`.

Why is that? Am I call the script in the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: Replace that with `abc=abc ./bash.sh` to set `abc` as an environment variable instead of a positional argument (which nothing in your script currently reads).

Comment: BTW, if it doesn't start with a line equivalent to `#!/bin/bash`, it *isn't* a bash script at all. (`#!/bin/sh` scripts also aren't bash scripts; they're *POSIX sh* scripts, which is a more restricted language).

Answer (score 1):

Bash positional arguments are set to `$1`, `$2`, etc. Change your script to:

```
abc=$1
echo "${abc:=123}"
```

this will make it so if the variable `abc` is unset the default value is echoed but if another value is passed on the command line `abc` will be set to that value.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a parameter and expecting to see it in an environment variable.

If you want to set an environment variable, you can do that *before* the script name:

```
$ cat foo
#!/bin/bash
echo "${abc:=123}"

$ ./foo
123

$ abc=hello ./foo
hello
```